# Zipalign Successful. Can't find output apk file

Tags: android, apk, android-sdk-tools

[image]

I manually zipalign my APK file in my folder and then stated that my output APK file should also be saved inside that folder. Why does that file not show up in that folder, after verification?

I used the cmd line

```
zipalign -f -v 4 "APK Folder"/app.apk "APK Folder"/appzip.apk
```

---

I manually zipalign my APK file in the tools folder also, using the cmd line

```
zipalign -f -v 4 app.apk appzip.apk
```

[image]

Comment: Have you properly verified your destination apk ?

Comment: I just updated the cmd I used.

Comment: Where is APK Folder?? You need to give a path of APK Folder in cmd.

Comment: The APK Folder is in the same folder as the folder the zipalign tool is in.

Comment: Its a better to put your APK file in tools folder. You need to change your path

Comment: I just did that. Still didn't give me an output APK file

Comment: Can you show me that one?

Comment: Updated the post again

Comment: Still you got same issue?

Comment: Yep. Is it possible to re-download zipalign? Could it be zipalign it's self?

Comment: Yes you can download it. But not issue because of it. Just try again.

Comment: @SeeYouSpaceCowboy if the output folder is located on C drive, then you may need to open the CMD `Run As Admin` ... maybe ...

Comment: YES! I had to run CMD as ADMIN! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue was fixed by running CMD as ADMIN, then running *zipalign.exe*